my terminal, running ursina code, is unable to load .blend files
I am using the terminal (MacOS) to execute my python code that uses .blend files 3D models. My terminal prints this error:
raise Exception('error: trying to load .blend file, but no blender installation was found. blender_paths:', application.blender_paths)
Exception: ('error: trying to load .blend file, but no blender installation was found. blender_paths:', {})


for reference, my code is below:
from ursina import *

app=Ursina()

e = Entity(model="huskyb", position = (0,0,0))


I have blender installed and I manually added the line below to ~/.zshrc:
export PATH="/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender:$PATH"

I also have tried to replace the file I'm trying to display with an .obj file and the code works as it should.

and the PATH is actually set in your shell?

@ruud yes, i saved the path that i added to ~/.zshrc. also, the terminal is able to launch the blender application independently of the code.

First, try turning the huskyb into huskyb.blend or you could try using an online converter to change it into an .obj file. Try making the path like game/models/huskyb because they cant search for huskyb in the same folder.

Ursina can't find blender automatically on MacOS. It should be automatic on Linux and Windows though. However, it's possible to point to a specific location by adding it to application.blender_paths (set application.blender_paths['default']) to use the same Blender for all .blend versions.
